# Why the WAF is "crashing" the website - Laravel

Tags: laravel, firewall, web-application-firewall

This is my first website in the Laravel framework. Website is running fine without the firewall. But whenever the firewall is enabled, the site is giving 502 or 504 server errors and thus the site is not loading.

As per hosting company opinion, the website is blocking the WAF because of laravel's security features. The WAF is always checking the connection to the site and server to make sure the site is still up.  So, the site security detects this as unwanted traffic after a while and probably blocks the WAF, thus getting a site error.

So what changes do I need to make on the website to resolve this issue?

We have found some packages on GitHub like Akaunting, SheildOn to install on the server. But I am not sure which package will help to resolve this issue. Or do I need to make any coding related changes in the website?